# I need to multiply a series of matrices

Tags: matrix

I need to perform a dot product on a large number of 2 x 2 matrices that I have defined to differ by even/odd subscripts (Ex: D-odd=x but D-even=y). The $\Pi$ function will not work because it does not perform dot products. Does anyone know how I can carry out this large series of matrix multiplications. Thanks

Comment: Could you please show your starting code? It's hard to have nothing to start from.

Answer (score 19):

If you have a list of matrices, you can apply a dot multiplication to all the matrices by changing the `Head` of the list to `Dot`. To illustrate this, I'll first define a set of matrices symbolically:

```
matrixList = With[{numberOfMatrices = 2},
  Table[Array[Subsuperscript["M", Row[{#1, #2}], i] &, {2, 2}], {i, 
    numberOfMatrices}]
  ]
```

> $\left\{\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \text{M}_{11}^1 & \text{M}_{12}^1 \\
>  \text{M}_{21}^1 & \text{M}_{22}^1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \text{M}_{11}^2 & \text{M}_{12}^2 \\
>  \text{M}_{21}^2 & \text{M}_{22}^2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\right\}$

This contains just two matrices for display reasons, but you can change `numberOfMatrices` to anything you like.

Now the answer to your question is just:

```
Apply[Dot, matrixList]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \text{M}_{11}^1 \text{M}_{11}^2+\text{M}_{12}^1
>    \text{M}_{21}^2 & \text{M}_{11}^1
>    \text{M}_{12}^2+\text{M}_{12}^1 \text{M}_{22}^2 \\
>  \text{M}_{11}^2 \text{M}_{21}^1+\text{M}_{21}^2
>    \text{M}_{22}^1 & \text{M}_{12}^2
>    \text{M}_{21}^1+\text{M}_{22}^1 \text{M}_{22}^2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Edit**

I noticed that there is a significant speedup over the above method, and also over the equivalent approach using `Fold` mentioned by J.M., if I partition the list of matrices beforehand and do the dot products in two steps:

```
With[{numberOfMatrices = 17},
  matrixList1 = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {numberOfMatrices, 2, 2}]; 
  matrixList = 
   Table[Array[Subsuperscript["M", Row[{#1, #2}], i] &, {2, 2}], {i, 
     numberOfMatrices}]];


comparisonRule = Thread[Flatten[matrixList] -> Flatten[matrixList1]];

AbsoluteTiming[res1 = Apply[Dot, matrixList];]

(* ==> {0.060968, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 res2 = Apply[Dot, Dot @@@ Partition[matrixList, UpTo[4]]];]

(* ==> {0.00059, Null} *)

(res1 /. comparisonRule) == (res2 /. comparisonRule)

(* ==> True *)
```

The speed gain is more dramatic for larger lists of matrices, and one may have to play with the partition size. I used the command [`UpTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpTo.html) in `Partition` to allow the remainder partition to be of variable size.

If you want to test this for larger lists, I suggest omitting the test on the last line because it will be very slow (I already tried to speed it up by using random numbers in place of the symbolic matrix elements).

The original idea was to use `ParallelMap` on the partition, but the overhead due to parallelization eats up the speed gain with the tested example.

Comment: Yes, you could also take a `List` and change its head to `Times` if you want to get the normal multiplication of all elements in a list. But just to clarify: `Dot` is really very different from `Times` because conventional matrix multiplication is not commutative, whereas `Times` doesn't care about the order of the factors. BTW - strange that @NasserM.Abbasi appears here as your name. That's not you, right?

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi  lol, it's too late at night here...

Comment: is there a way to parallelize this? I have a similar problem where I need to multiply a lot of 2x2 matrices in a list. I used your method and there doesn't seem to be a difference between that and using a Do loop to multiply them. This method is more elegant but not faster.

Comment: If your matrices are numerical, you could try to speed things up by using machine-precision arithmetic, e.g. by wrapping the list in `N` before doing the product. That would be much more of a gain than trying to parallelize the product.

Comment: doesn't that mean that there is some truncating going on? i need this product to calculate the transmission coefficient through multi layers and I might end up with artefacts.

Comment: I think that won't be an issue in typical applications. But I'm only guessing. Problems tend to appear only at very specific wavelengths but those isolated points could be dropped. That's just my blind guess, not knowing anything about your case.

Comment: I know what you mean. I don't want to hijack this thread thou. I was just curious if parallelization was possible.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `Partition` on your list, then `ParallelEvaluate` to use my answer on each sublist, then combine the results.

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it only works if the number of matrices is a power of 2. If not, `Partition` will drop the elements that it cannot pair and you end up with the wrong result...

Comment: @lucian You can use the new `UpTo` to fix that problem. I'll add something to my answer shortly.

Comment: I completely missed `UpTo`! I will give this a try definitely!

Comment: @Jens Regarding the `RecursionLimit`, it might be worth mentioning that one could just use a minimum partition size of `m=Ceiling[num/$RecursionLimit]` where `n` is the total number of matrices. What I am actually interested in: do you (or someone else) have any intuition about how partition size has to be chosen such that it is at least somehow time-efficient? If this multiplication is part of a function and the number of matrices may vary dramatically from call to call, it is a NoGo for me to benchmark the partition size every time :( Might it be something like `Max[m,$ProcessorCount]`?

Comment: @Lukas I agree that some more experimentation is needed to find the optimal partition. You suggestion using `$ProcessorCount` sounds like a good guess - and I can't think of anything better if you can't hard-code the approximate dimensions.

Comment: @Jens A small query `UpTo` why `4`? How to decide this? Does this depend on matrix size(choice)?

Comment: @L.K. I found this by experimentation - so unfortunately I don't have a general rule for the best choice right now. It might be interesting to do a series of experiments, but then I wouldn't necessarily trust if that remains true in the next version...

Answer (score 5):

You can `ParallelCombine` as well.  This has the added benefit of working on a list of more than the iteration limit of the session. My limit is 4096 so I would not be able to dot product more than 4096 matrices without using this or a similar method.

```
matrices = RandomReal[2, {10000, 2, 2}];

ParallelCombine[Dot[Sequence @@ ##] &, matrices, Dot]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting observation about the limit of factors (+1). I didn't dare to try it for 10000 *symbolic* matrices, but I chose 100 to compare to my method. With that, I can still make my (non-parallel) method run about twice as fast as `ParallelCombine` by choosing `UpTo[10]` in `Partition`. The more matrices, the better `ParallelCombine` seems to get.

Answer (score 5):

For very long lists, it may be beneficial to iterate Jens' answer. This can be achieved using `NestWhile`

```
listmultiplier[list_, partitionwidth_: 5] := NestWhile[Dot @@@ Partition[#, partitionwidth, partitionwidth, 1, {}] &, list, Dimensions[#][[1]] > 1 &][[1]]
```

This code partitions the list into sublists containing at most `partitionwidth` matrices, applies `Dot` to each sublist and iterates until the final list contains a single matrix. As I am using version 10.2, the UpTo command is not available but can be replicated using the optional commands in `Partition`

For large lists, iterating can offer substantial savings:

```
matrixlist = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4000, 20, 20}];

AbsoluteTiming[method1 = Apply[Dot, matrixlist];]

(* ==> {26.4274, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[method2 = Apply[Dot, Dot @@@ Partition[matrixlist, 5, 5, 1, {}]];]

(* ==> {5.50295, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[method3 = listmultiplier[matrixlist];]

(* ==> {0.204352, Null} *)

Chop[method2] == Chop[method1]

(* ==> True *)

Chop[method3] == Chop[method1]

(* ==> True *)
```

Comment: Wow, this is great!

Comment: That is great, unfortunately couldn't understand the code. It is possible to write about the top code(above my head)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use `Fold[]` along with `Dot[]`. Using Jens's example, you can do `Fold[Dot, IdentityMatrix[2], matrixList]`. Note that your initial identity matrix must have dimensions that conform with the dimensions of your other matrices.

Comment: However, it should be mentioned that the `Fold` approach is (on my machine, for `matrixList= = RandomReal[2, {10000, 2, 2}]`) an order of magnitude slower than Jens' approach using `Partition`.