# Multiply all matrices in an array

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, products

Disclaimer: I'm new to Mathematica.

I have an array $\gamma[i]$ of length $n$, each element of which holds an $m\times m$-matrix. I would like to multiply all of them,
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \gamma[i].$$
I started out thinking this should be incredibly simple but after searching through the documentation and on StackExchange for over an hour, the only information I could find is [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15555/i-need-to-multiply-a-series-of-matrices), in which the best answer suggests
`Apply[Dot, matrixList]`. Since my matrices are not in a list this doesn't seem to help me much.

Comment: In *Mathematica* lingo an array is a list.  Do you mean each matrix is store in a separate "variable" named `gamma[1]`, `gamma[2]`, and so forth  (*not* `gamma[[1]]` as in a list-array)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Correct.

Comment: `Apply[Dot, Array[gamma, n]]`?

Comment: `Module[{res = gamma[1]}, Do[res = res . gamma[i], {i, 2, n}]; res]` is a C-like way to go....The previous might be more efficient.  Would have to test.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much, the first works nicely. What would I have had to search for in the documentation to find this?

Comment: You might not find it exactly, I suppose.  You might have looked up your keyword "Array", and combined it with the linked question.  Sometimes it's hard to put together all the pieces, until you've solved several problems like this one.

Comment: Instead of `Array`, there's also `Table[gamma[i], {i, n}]`, too.  And `gamma /@ Range[n]`.... There are usually several ways to solve any problem involving lists and arrays. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Related question: If I wanted to take the Kronecker product of a matrix $n$ times with itself, would I have to go about it in the same way and create a list containing that matrix $n$ times, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK there is no `KroneckerPower`-like function. I would use `KroneckerProduct @@ Table[m, {n}]`. (`@@` is short infix for `Apply`.)  `Table` will copy only pointers to `m`, so it's memory-efficient.  But the Kronecker product will be so much bigger, that's not a major consideration here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a sequence of matrices, `gamma[1]`, `gamma[2]`,..., `gamma[n]`, you can use [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) and apply `Dot as in the linked question, [I need to multiply a series of matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15555/i-need-to-multiply-a-series-of-matrices):

```
Apply[Dot, Array[gamma, n]]
```

Comment: …or, `Array[gamma, n, 1, Dot]`.