# Taking the product of a list of matrices

Tags: matrix, core-language

Suppose I create a list of matrices:

```
data = Table[RandomInteger[5, {2, 2}], 5]
```

Which produces:

```
{{{0, 5}, {2, 1}}, {{5, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{4, 4}, {0, 1}}, {{5, 3}, {2, 
   5}}, {{2, 0}, {5, 0}}}
```

How can I quickly take the product of these five matrices?

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15555 Also check the answers there for insight to performance if that is important ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Dot@@data` should do what you're looking for. It replaces the main `Head`, `List`, with `Dot`, which just multiplies all of the matrices—which used to comprise the `List` data—together.

```
data = Table[RandomInteger[5, {2, 2}], 5];

MatrixForm /@ data
```

[image]

```
Dot @@ data // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Kalsiqi Nice answer! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

This question reminded me something I did some time ago when I was computing Lyapunov exponents of maps, i.e. discrete dynamical systems. Let me share it here.

What I needed was to compute the matrix product successively from the end (I wanted to be able to plot a convergence plot), i.e. have access to `data[[5]]`, `data[[4]].data[[5]]` etc. I had $10^4$ matrices in one go and repeated it for $10^5$ realisations, so forming a `Table` explicitly was numerically very expensive. So I came up with this solution:

```
v[1] = Last[data];
v[n_] := v[n] = data[[Length[data] - (n - 1)]].v[n - 1]
```

which, even when `Length@data` is huge, gives almost instant access to any step.

While this in fact gives an answer to your question, as `v[Length@data]` will give the same result as `Dot@@data`, it is of course less elegant and efficient than `Dot@@data`. But in case you would like to look into the intermediate steps (noting that the multiplications are done starting from the end of the matrices stored in `data`) this will provide them.

---

**EDIT:** In case one wants to access the intermediate steps starting from the beginning of `data`, i.e. to access the *accumulative dot product*:

```
p[1] = First[data];
p[n_] := p[n] = p[n - 1].data[[n]]
```